# How to use yeoman conditionals within sass files

Tags: import, sass, conditional-statements, yeoman

depending on an answer of a question in yeoman I want to import different files within sass.

For example I am trying to use this here in style.scss

```
<% if(sassFramework) { %>
    @import 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass/lib/bootstrap';
<% } >
```

Though it leads to an error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/rx/dist/rx.all.js:9156
        throw e;
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

However, exactly the same syntax mentioned above works in html templates. So what is the problem with it?